# Resize NSWindow given the new size of the contentView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

How do you resize a `NSWindow` given the new size of the `contentView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) resizeWindowWithContentSize:(NSSize)contentSize animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat titleBarHeight = self.window.frame.size.height - ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).frame.size.height;
    CGSize windowSize = CGSizeMake(contentSize.width, contentSize.height + titleBarHeight);

    // Optional: keep it centered
    float originX = self.window.frame.origin.x + (self.window.frame.size.width - windowSize.width) / 2;
    float originY = self.window.frame.origin.y + (self.window.frame.size.height - windowSize.height) / 2;
    NSRect windowFrame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, windowSize.width, windowSize.height);

    [self.window setFrame:windowFrame display:YES animate:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do —

```
[window setContentSize:newContentSize]
```

There are also methods to convert between window and content sizes:

- `- (NSRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(NSRect)windowFrame`
- `- (NSRect)frameRectForContentRect:(NSRect)windowContent`